# Why can't I use my great prophet to enhance my religion?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I have just bought a great Prophet in my Holy City but the 'enhance religion option' doesn't appear. Why not? What can I do to have this option? I need to enhance my religion!

Comment: Have you already enhanced your religion?

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it once. Then I had the choice of a great person, I chose a prophet but I couldn't enhance my religion. Then I bought one in my holy city and same thing: no enhance religion option. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Thank you for yet another episode of the wonderful saga of hilarious or confusing question titles, when read on other SE sites out of the context of Arqade.

Comment: You are so welcome, KRyan! 
And a question, if they are so AMUSING and CONFUSING, why are you wasting your time with them? Ah, that's right - you have nothing better to do! Well, enjoy then!

Comment: @KRyan paid you a high compliment. Why would you throw out an insult in response? Or maybe I misunderstood you, too.

Comment: To echo @DavidHarkness, yes, it was very much intended to be a compliment. One of the best things about Arqade, and one of its “calling cards” so to speak among SE sites, is the wonderful titles that catch you off-guard.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood - the problem sometimes with a written comment out of the blue. I certainly didn't mean to offend and thank you for the compliment. If the title of my first post counts as confusing & amusing, I'm sure I'll have more to contribute in the future and, therefore, keep you entertained!

Comment: Bruh. 5 years later, and you still haven't selected the top answer.

Answer (score 23):

To enhance a religion, a great prophet needs to:

- Be in the holy city of your religion- not the capital if these are different cities.
- Have all its spread religion uses remaining. If you use him to spread your religion even once, you can't use him to enhance your religion.
- Be of your religion. Are you certain the city you bought him in was of your religion at the time?
- Be of an unenhanced religion. You cannot enhance a religion twice.

Make sure all of these are true, especially the second one.

Comment: this should solve it ^^

Comment: Ah, that's the problem then. I have already enhanced my religion. But I thought you could enhance it more than once in a game. Isn't that the idea? To make it stronger and give you advantages?

Comment: @AJ.L Great Prophets have three uses: enhancing a religion, spreading religion (while destroying other religions, like a Missionary and Inquisitor rolled into one unit), and building Holy Sites. Enhancing your religion is the first thing you should do, but you can only do it once.

Comment: @AJ.L No. Enhancing a religion only happens once per religion. If you want to improve it further, take the Reformation policy from the Piety tree- it gives you an additional belief.

Comment: Right, got it. Thanks so much for taking the time to help.

Comment: @AJ.L - You should select an answer then.  That's probably the best way to thank the answerer.

Comment: @AJ.L If you're really into getting more tenets, the other alternative is to play Byzantines. You get one more when you enhance your religion.

Comment: Thank you Calyth, but I'm only just getting the hang of Brave New World. I just uploaded it and at the moment I just think it's so long to play, although I like some of the new concepts. I didn't know I was going to lose the old Civ 5 when I upgraded. My bad :(

Comment: @AJ.L Go to DLCs in the main menu. Turn things on or off as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the Great Prophet in the holy city of that religion (the city that your first Great Prophet founded it in). Then, the option should appear at the top of his command list.

Comment: But he is in my holy city - that's where I bought him.

Comment: Wow, I've enhanced plenty of religions, and I had no idea of this requirement. Guess I've been lucky since autopurchased prophets must appear in the Holy city.